# How to solve exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

```
import java.util.Scanner

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val reader = Scanner(System.`in`)
    print("Enter a number: ")
    var integer:Int = reader.nextInt()
    println("You entered: $integer")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must check `reaader.hasNextInt()` before call `reader.nextInt()`

```
import java.util.Scanner

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val reader = Scanner(System.`in`)
    print("Enter a number: ")
    if (reader.hasNextInt()) {
        val integer = reader.nextInt()
        println("You entered: $integer")
    }
}
```